# Pandas df - Limit results per group

Tags: python, pandas

I have this df:

[image]

I want to limit the number of rows per each group of: attribute_1 & attribute_2.
Limit to 10 rows per group.
As you can see in the example above, group (gump-baba) has 10 rows and also group (gump-forrest) has 10 rows I want to keep 5 and get rid of the last 5 (let's say the table is sorted according to some metric).
I want to keep the table exactly as it is (with attribute_3 and all rest of the metrics).

I tried df.groupby(...).head(5) but without any success. Any ideas on how to accomplish this?

Answer (score 1):

You can use `groupby` and then `apply` with a `lambda` to extract only the first few elements that you want. For example:

```
a = [1]*3 + [2]*3 + [3]*3
b = [*range(0, 3)]*3
c = ['x']*3 + ['y']*3 + ['z']*3
somedf = pd.DataFrame({'a': a, 'b': b, 'c': c})
```

In this example, extract the first two elements of columns `b` and `c` for each value of `a`:

```
newdf = somedf.groupby('a').apply(lambda x: x.iloc[0:2])
```

Answer (score 0):

you can do something like this might work

```
df=df[df["attribute_2"]=="baba"].head(5) 
+df[df["attribute_2"]=="forrest"].head(5)
```